# MSI Installer prompting for elevated instructions C# Visual Studio Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, visual-studio-project

I have configured a msi installer using VS Projects and when installing it is working fine with the accounts of all users in my organization. The problem arises when someone tries to uninstall the same. it starts prompting for elevated access which not everyone has. What I need?

1. A way to uninstall for every user the same way anyone can install it.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: is it installing in Program Files or each users install it in their respective profiles?

Comment: Installing in C:\<Some folder>

Comment: is the application registered in HKLM or HKCU?

Comment: registered in HKCU